# How to upload ASP.NET MVC 5 website to server via Web Interface (Plesk)

Tags: ftp, asp.net-mvc-5, plesk

I made a website with visual studio 2013 (MVC 5). I published my VS project to a local directory and uploaded all like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUfyN.png

but in the website preview an error occurs

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

What Interface does your server run? If its Apache you need to Download an Extension for your Webserver. If you want to run asax on a webpage. If not use a language like html and css to show your website